# retrieve members email from 1:1 conversation bot framework message extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

So i created a message extension using bot framework v4.
What am trying to do is to retrieve members emails in 1:1 conversation using the message extension on `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync`. However am getting 403 Forbidden.

The next step I tried to add the Bot to the conversation using AdaptiveCards and I get the following error "Something went wrong, please try again later." And when checking bot in channel registration I found the below issue:

> The bot is not part of the conversation roster

So I created a graph connection and granted admin consent.Now when using GetUserTokenAsync after submit action  I receive "Something went wrong, please try again later." (Testing connection created from portal.azure.com returns a token)

I find it a little bit weird to not able to retrieve what's already obvious. I can see the contact email and name so the 403 is absurd in my own opinion or I might be doing something wrong.
SO my question is either how to check the detailed errors that are returned or is there any easier way to retrieve members emails.

Thank you

Comment: An additional thing, it is working fine from the "Test in web chat" in bot channels registration.However from microsoft teams ,even when trying with the "teams auth" sample solution provided, I receive the Sign in card and after clicking the button nothing happens.After waiting for more than 15 minutes I receive "Login was not successful please try again."

Comment: Are you able to debug the bot locally through Teams [using ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)? Are you using the approaches outlined in the [Teams Auth](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) sample?

Comment: @DanaV yep debug and the approaches  outlined.In debug mode it hits the LoginStepAsync method .Just a display of the Login button and after clicking the button nothing.

Comment: @DanaV so in the authentication of the APP the  redirect URI should be " https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect "?

Comment: I believe so. Did you get this working?

Comment: @DanaV not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the bot manifest file it seems that I didn't add the below to the json:

```
  "validDomains": [
    "token.botframework.com",
    "*.ngrok.io"
  ]
```